# Using visibility slider with trisurf in plotly python

Tags: python, slider, plotly

I would like to use plotly in python to plot a torus, and then use a slider to move an object along the torus. So far I am able to display all of the objects at once, or just slide to see the individual slices without the torus. The biggest difference between the two cases is how the information is passed to `plotly.plot`: in the first, I've extended a `trisurf` object, whereas in the second, I've appended to a python `list`.  I would like to have the torus always visible, and then as the slider moves, the different circles would appear/disappear. I apologize if I've missed something in the plotly documentation.

**Everything at once**

```
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

## Draw torus
u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
U,V = np.meshgrid(u,v)
u = U.flatten()
v = V.flatten()

x = (3 + (np.cos(v)))*np.cos(u)
y = (3 + (np.cos(v)))*np.sin(u)
z = np.sin(v)

X = (3 + (np.cos(V)))*np.cos(U)
Y = (3 + (np.cos(V)))*np.sin(U)
Z = np.sin(V)

points2D = np.vstack([u,v]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)
simplices = tri.simplices

torus = FF.create_trisurf(x=x, y=y, z=z, simplices=simplices, title="Torus", aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.3),plot_edges=True, width=1000)

for i in range(10,13):
    trace0 = go.Scatter3d(
            x = (3+np.cos(v))*np.cos(u[i]),
            y = (3+np.cos(v))*np.sin(u[i]),
            z = np.sin(v),
            marker=dict(
                size=1,
                color='red',
            ),
            line=dict(
                 color='red',
                 width=4,
            ),
    )
    torus['data'].extend(go.Data([trace0]))

fig=dict(data=torus)
plotly.offline.plot(fig,validate=False)
```

**The slider without the torus**

```
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

## Draw torus
u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
U,V = np.meshgrid(u,v)
u = U.flatten()
v = V.flatten()

x = (3 + (np.cos(v)))*np.cos(u)
y = (3 + (np.cos(v)))*np.sin(u)
z = np.sin(v)

X = (3 + (np.cos(V)))*np.cos(U)
Y = (3 + (np.cos(V)))*np.sin(U)
Z = np.sin(V)

points2D = np.vstack([u,v]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)
simplices = tri.simplices

plot_data=list()

torus = FF.create_trisurf(x=x, y=y, z=z, simplices=simplices, title="Torus", aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.3),plot_edges=True, width=1000)
plot_data.append(torus)

for i in range(10,13):
    trace0 = go.Scatter3d(
            x = (3+np.cos(v))*np.cos(u[i]),
            y = (3+np.cos(v))*np.sin(u[i]),
            z = np.sin(v),
            marker=dict(
                size=1,
                color='red',
            ),
            line=dict(
                 color='red',
                 width=4,
            ),
    )
    plot_data.append(trace0)

steps = list()

for i in range(4):
        step = dict(
        method='restyle',
        args=['visible', [False] * (4)],
        label='Time Step {}'.format(i)
        )
        step['args'][1][i] = True
        steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(steps=steps)]

layout=dict(sliders=sliders)

fig=dict(data=plot_data,layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig,validate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found [here on the plotly forum](https://community.plot.ly/t/combining-trisurf-and-scatter-plots-in-one-figure/2405). Summarizing, you cannot directly pass the `trisurf` to `plot`, because it contains its own `layout` key. So instead you need to strip off the data from the trisurf and then pass that. In the 'slider without torus' code above, the line

```
plot_data.append(torus)`
```

should be replaced with

```
plot_data.append(torus.data[0])
plot_data.append(torus.data[1])
```

and then it will work as intended.